# Tensorflow graph transformation breaks with quantize_nodes

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm attempting to quantize a netowrk with the example from the repo.
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph --

```
in_graph="freeze.pb" --out_graph="optimized_freeze.pb" \
--inputs='...' \
--outputs='..,..,..' \
--transforms='
  add_default_attributes
  strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="1,299,299,3")
  remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)
  fold_constants(ignore_errors=true)
  fold_batch_norms
  fold_old_batch_norms
  quantize_weights
  quantize_nodes
  strip_unused_nodes
  sort_by_execution_order'
```

And getting the TraceBack:
Note that if I try the same thing without `quantize_nodes` it works fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 686, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    input_tensors_as_shapes, status)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status)) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 64 for 'import/resnet_model/batch_normalization/FusedBatchNorm' (op: 'FusedBatchNorm') with input shapes: [?,4,?,64], [64], [64], [0], [0].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "save_model.py", line 75, in <module>
    "hair_mask": 'import/nn_predict/hair_mask_prediction:0',   File "save_model.py", line 53, in freeze_model
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 687, in import_graph_def
    ops.set_shapes_for_outputs(op)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2496, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    return _set_shapes_for_outputs(op)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2469, in _set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2399, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 627, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    require_shape_fn)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 691, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message) ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 64 for 'import/resnet_model/batch_normalization/FusedBatchNorm' (op: 'FusedBatchNorm') with input shapes: [?,4,?,64], [64], [64], [0], [0].
```

Comment: I am getting this error " Node 'bn2a_branch1/beta/read' expects to be colocated with unknown node 'bn2a_branch1/beta"